# Jasmine unit tests - does any one know what $provide, $provide.decorator and $provide.service are for?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Jasmine unit tests - does any one know what $provide, $provide.decorator and $provide.service are for?

What would I use them for and does anyone know any good you tube videos and/or links for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: its `$provide` not `$provider`

Comment: ok, changed the text above

Comment: Do you know much about $provider and what its for and how to use it etc?

Comment: Err… they seem to be part of Angular, not Jasmine.

Comment: `$provide` is API used by angular to register various component internally like `$provide.controller` ,`$provide.factory`, etc API [code here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L642-L649), In jasmine you could use it for modifying module component in config phase..

Comment: In unit testing is it used to mock or get services/factories?#